# How to add a file as attachment to .ics file using ics.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, icalendar

Using https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js/. Using javascript add photo as attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Read the RFC5545 Specification. https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-1-1-attachment.html   You attach by adding URL to the attachment.